# Probability and measure theory problem

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, measure-theory

I am self learning the measure and probability theory and came across this problem. This might look very simple but appreciate any help or a hint in the right direction.

When $X$ is a random variable that follows a normal distribution, what is the maximum number of points for which we can set the probability measure to zero before the distribution changes and what happens if the measure $\mu (\emptyset) \neq 0$?

My thought is that the number of points $n$ can rise to infinity as then the sample size becomes infinite allowing the zero probability events. Is this correct?

Comment: $\mu(\emptyset)\ne 0$ means that $\mu$ is not a measure. // Some weird stuff happens in measure theory. Infinite sets can have measure zero, such as the rational numbers. Even uncountable sets can have measure zero! The Cantor set is an example of this.

Comment: Your question is inconsistent: you first specify a random variable and its distribution, which implies a specific probability measure, and then you ask about "setting" the measure to zero.  Could you please explain this process and what you mean by it?